# Runtime error with the AmazonEc2Client when relocating the package using maven shade

Tags: java, maven, amazon-ec2, maven-shade-plugin, javaagents

I'm working on a java agent and using the maven shade plugin to relocate my dependencies so I avoid class path conflicts and issues. I'm not super familiar with the shade plugin as of yet but I'm running into this issue where I have told the plugin to shade my dependencies and prepend everything with `shaded` (e.g. com.amazonaws.services.ec2 -> shaded.amazonaws.services.ec2), however, when I run my application, which builds an AmazonEc2Client, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: shaded.com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to instantiate request handler chain for client: com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.transform.EC2RequestHandler
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.handlers.HandlerChainFactory.createRequestHandlerChain(HandlerChainFactory.java:158)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.handlers.HandlerChainFactory.newRequestHandlerChain(HandlerChainFactory.java:45)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.init(AmazonEC2Client.java:308)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.<init>(AmazonEC2Client.java:297)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.<init>(AmazonEC2Client.java:280)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.build(AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.java:61)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.build(AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.java:27)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at my.sample.project.Boot.<clinit>(Boot.java:49)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.transform.EC2RequestHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:177)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:136)
    at shaded.com.amazonaws.handlers.HandlerChainF
```

Here is a snippet of my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Premain-Class>my.sample.project.Boot</Premain-Class>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>com.amazonaws</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>shaded.com.amazonaws</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*:*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And here's a snippet of the code block instantiating the EC2 client.

```
public static void premain(final String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        log.info("Connecting to AWS...");
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.withRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(DEFAULT_RETRY_CONDITION,
                                                            new PredefinedBackoffStrategies.ExponentialBackoffStrategy(500, 8000),
                                                            DEFAULT_MAX_ERROR_RETRY,
                                                            true));
        AwsRequests.client = AmazonEC2Client.builder()
                                            .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
                                            .build();
    }
```

The issue stems from when the amazonec2client is actually being built, it looks like it still expects to find the class in the `com.amazonaws.services.ec2` package but it has been shaded to the `shaded.com.amazonaws.services.ec2` package. My understanding was that the shade plugin would update the underlying code to point to the correct shaded packages, am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue, the AmazonEC2client init method expects the following resources to be available:

```
requestHandler2s.addAll(chainFactory.newRequestHandlerChain("/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/request.handlers"));
requestHandler2s.addAll(chainFactory.newRequestHandler2Chain("/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/request.handler2s"));
```

I just did an exclusion on my pom.xml for anything under the transform package in amazonaws, like so:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.transform.*</exclude>
</excludes>
```

And it worked, hopefully this helps someone in the future!